# Avoid using rowspan for email comms

Tags: html, email, html-table

I've always used rowspan for web site development but now designing and developing email comms rowspan, it appears constantly breaks. In multiple clients it displays with a 10/20px gap. How can I avoid using row span even if I need to have two images side by side in an email (such as a header)?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>StPatricksDAy-PostCard</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (StPatricksDAy-PostCard.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="657" height="684" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="6">
            <img src="images/StPatricksDAy-PostCard_01.gif" width="19" height="643" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/StPatricksDAy-PostCard_02.gif" width="636" height="14" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="6">
            <img src="images/StPatricksDAy-PostCard_03.gif" width="2" height="643" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/StPatricksDAy-PostCard_04.gif" width="636" height="96" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/StPatricksDAy-PostCard_05.gif" width="636" height="9" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/StPatricksDAy-PostCard_06.jpg" width="257" height="523" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/StPatricksDAy-PostCard_07.gif" width="368" height="449" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/StPatricksDAy-PostCard_08.gif" width="11" height="524" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/StPatricksDAy-PostCard_09.gif" width="368" height="74" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/StPatricksDAy-PostCard_10.gif" width="625" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <img src="images/StPatricksDAy-PostCard_11.gif" width="657" height="28" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <img src="images/StPatricksDAy-PostCard_12.gif" width="657" 

    height="13" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is a good question.  I have tried playing with it a bit, but I can't seem to get rid of the spacing under the images in the `<td>`s.  If someone else wants to help, here's the jFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GUEFT/

Comment: I've been told nesting tables inside a parent table is the way to get around rowspan for emails. How do you nest tables, is it as simple as inserting another table in a row?

Comment: Yes, http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/tables/nestingtables.html